# Proving that $\tilde{H}^i(\mathbb R P^2 \vee S^3; \mathbb Z_2) = \tilde{H}^i(\mathbb R P^2; \mathbb Z_2) \oplus \tilde{H}^i(S^3; \mathbb Z_2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I want to prove the following statement:

$\tilde{H}^i(\mathbb R P^2 \vee S^3; \mathbb Z_2) = \tilde{H}^i(\mathbb R P^2; \mathbb Z_2) \oplus  \tilde{H}^i(S^3; \mathbb Z_2)$

but I am not sure how to prove it, I am guessing that it should be proved using Mayer Vietoris sequence as I think I have seen something similar to this but for homology before( I am not sure where did I saw it though).

Could anyone show me the details of the proof please?

**Here is my trial:**

Here are my A, B and X. $A$ is the upper hemisphere of $\mathbb R P^2$ and $B$ is the lower hemisphere of $S^3$ and $X$ is the figure on the right below (their union with an intersection strip between A and B):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now I know that $\tilde{H^i}(\mathbb RP^{n}, \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for $0 < i \leq n$ and 0 when $i=0.$ Then I can write the Mayier Vietoris sequence as follows:

$... \tilde{H^2}(A \cap B) \xrightarrow{\phi} \tilde{H^2}(A) \oplus \tilde{H^2}(B)  \xrightarrow{\psi} \tilde{H^2}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial} \tilde{H^1}(A \cap B) \xrightarrow{\phi} \tilde{H^1}(A) \oplus \tilde{H^1}(B) \xrightarrow{\psi} \tilde{H^1}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial}0$

but then why always we must have the reduced homology of the intersection is 0 and why the space $X$ can be considered as $\mathbb R P^2 \vee S^3$?

Could someone explain this to me please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZAG.png

Comment: Does it help to know that the statement holds for any wedge sum of reasonable spaces with any coefficient group?

Comment: Indeed, use Mayer-Vietoris. Ideally, you would want to decompose $\mathbb{RP}^2\vee S^3$ as union of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $S^3$, but those are not quite open in the wedge sum, so try taking slightly larger open subspaces that are homotopy-equivalent to these.

Comment: Let me edit my question with the corresponding Mayer Vietoris Sequence and you if you do not mind check it for me please.

Comment: @TabesBridges I am not sure how will this help, could you clarify please?

Comment: I'm just saying that this is a general fact about homology, that $\tilde H^i(X\vee Y, G) \cong \tilde H^i(X,G)\oplus \tilde H^i(Y,G)$. It has nothing to do with the specifics of the $\mathbb R P^2$, $S^3$, or $\mathbb Z_2$. That said, the general case can, I think, be deduced by the same (Mayer-Vietoris)-type argument that you are thinking about for this specific situation.

Comment: @TabesBridges I edited my question to include more details. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to show that, for a point in each space involved in the wedge, there is a neighborhood of that point which deformation retracts to that point. This is true for any simplicial complex (any $0$-simplex has such a neighborhood) or more generally any CW complex. If $(X,v)$ and $(Y,w)$ are two such pairs of (space, nice point), then form the wedge by gluing $v$ to $w$. Let $V \subseteq X$ and $W \subseteq Y$ be  neighborhoods which retract to $v$ and $w$, respectively. Now apply Mayer-Vietoris to $A = X \cup W$ and $B = V \cup Y$. (Think of $X \cup W$ as being $X$ with a little fluff added: $X \cup W$ will be homotopy equivalent to $X$ and hence have the same homology as $X$, but constructed so that $X$ is in the interior of $X \cup W$, as required by the statement of Mayer-Vietoris.) Their intersection is $V \vee W$, which deformation retracts to the wedge point $v=w$, and so is contractible. Therefore Mayer-Vietoris will give
$$
\tilde{H}_n(X \vee Y) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(Y)
$$
for each $n$.

Alternatively: first prove that if $X \amalg Y$ is the disjoint union, then $H_n(X \amalg Y) \cong H_n(X) \oplus H_n(Y)$. In fact, prove a relative version of this:
$$
H_n(X \amalg Y, \{v\}\amalg \{w\}) \cong H_n(X, v) \oplus H_n(Y, w).
$$
With the assumption above about nice neighborhoods of $v$ and $w$, we get isomorphisms
$$
H_n(X \amalg Y, \{v\}\amalg \{w\}) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X \amalg Y/ \{v\}\amalg \{w\})) = \tilde{H}_n(X \vee Y) \\
H_n(X, v) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X) \\
H_n(Y, w) \cong \tilde{H}_n(Y)
$$
The first of these happens because when we take the quotient, we are collapsing $\{v\}\amalg \{w\}$ to a single point — we are constructing the wedge.

Comment: where in Hatcher you got the idea of alternatively?

Comment: but I am asking about the reduced cohomology not homology..... I edited my Mayer Vietoris sequence ..... sorry about that.

Comment: what is the reduced homology of $S^3$ with $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ coefficients?

Comment: what is the reduced homology of $\mathbb R P^3$ with $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ coefficients?

Comment: Sorry about missing the cohomology/homology distinction in your question. My answer remains unchanged: the arguments work the same in each case. (You really just need to know that the (co)homology of the intersection is zero, and then apply the long exact sequence.)

Comment: Maybe I missed something: do all ideas have to come from Hatcher?

Comment: @Secretly: these are standard computations in algebraic topology. If you are having problems with those computations, please ask a new question on this site.

Comment: @Secretly: or if you just want the answer, visit https://sagecell.sagemath.org and enter the commands `S3 = simplicial_complexes.Sphere(3)` and `S3.homology(base_ring=GF(2))`, and similarly for `RP3 = simplicial_complexes.RealProjectiveSpace(3)`.